# Javascript: create a stop/start function?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a function that will start and stop on demand.

To explain this better I've created this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/93kk7tr0/

Basically, I need to run the `myTimer();` function every 5 seconds and when the button is clicked, I need to stop the `setInterval` until I call the `myTimer()` again.

When i run my code, I only the get the alert('testing..'); once when the page loads. so its like the `setInterval` is not even firing.

THIS IS MY ENTIRE CODE:

```
var myVar;

function myStartFunction() {
    myVar = setInterval(function(){ myTimer() }, 5000);
}

function myTimer() {
alert('teesting...');
}

function myStopFunction() {
    clearInterval(myVar);
}   

myTimer();
```

Can someone please advice on this issue?

Comment: You never call `myStartFunction`

Comment: You are not calling my start function

Comment: @trincot, OMG, school boy error.... im so tried i cant even think.. lol thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setInterval(myTimer, 5000);` and you need to call your `myStartFunction()` somewhere:

```
var myVar;

function myStartFunction() {
    myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 5000);
}

function myTimer() {
alert('teesting...');
}

function myStopFunction() {
    clearInterval(myVar);
}   

myStartFunction();       // <<< start it!
```